# Can't get some simple Haskell code to compile, no matter how many different ways I try it

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a Haskell function that takes in a tree, and replaces every node with a pair containing the height of the subtree at that node, and the original node

Depending on where I place my parenthesis in the last line of code, I get all kinds of different errors. I know my height function works because I've used it for different functions previously. I'm clearly not grouping things together correctly, because I've gotten everything from not giving enough arguments to max, to giving too many arguments to pairs. Please help! I'm really stuck here and making no progress because I'm just moving parenthesis back and forth.

```
data Tree a = Tip | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

getHeight :: Tree a -> Integer
getHeight Tip = 0
getHeight (Bin l _ r) = (max (getHeight l) (getHeight r)) +1

pairs :: Tree a -> Tree (Integer, a)
pairs Tip = Tip
pairs (Bin l x r) = (Bin (pairs l) ((max (left right)) x) (pairs r))
  where left = (getHeight l)
        right = (getHeight r)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to call a function with two arguments is my separating them with whitespace, like this:

```
f x y
```

Or in your case, this would be:

```
max left right
```

The way to construct a pair is with parens and a comma, like this:

```
(42, "foo")
```

Or in your case, this would be:

```
(max left right, x)
```

Summing all of that up, the line should be:

```
pairs (Bin l x r) = Bin (pairs l) (max left right, x) (pairs r)
```